# Branching Direction Deviation as in 'L' System

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm hoping someone smarter can accomplish this with fewer nodes.  Branches on most plants deviate direction when they split.  An 'L' system mimics this behavior to some degree however it is common for there to be only 1 level of branch splitting along an entire parent branch.  This solution solves this but at high cost.

[image]

[image]